# Spring Boot Test with Zuul filters is not picking up new instance of bean

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-test, netflix-zuul

I am using @SpringBootTest to run integration level tests with Zuul. Unfortunately I am running into an issue with the ApplicationContext refresh. Multiple instances of my RouteLocator is being created and the current instance isn't always being used. The RouteLocator I have implemented also implements the RefreshableRouteLocator. I created a very simple static field that increments by 1 every time an instance is created.

```
private static int id = 0;
private int instanceId = id++;
```

The tests leverage WireMock to mock the backend service that is being called from the the Zuul route. WireMock is configured to use a random port so I have @Before and @After methods to modify the route within the RouteLocator for each test.

```
@Autowired
protected LiveMigrationRouteLocator liveMigrationRouteLocator;

@Rule
public WireMockRule serviceA = new WireMockRule(Options.DYNAMIC_PORT);

@Rule
public WireMockRule serviceB = new WireMockRule(Options.DYNAMIC_PORT);

@Before
public void before() {
    LiveMigrationProperties routingProperties = liveMigrationRouteLocator.getRoutingProperties();
    for (LiveMigrationRoute route : routingProperties.getRoutes().values()) {
        route.setPrimaryUrl(route.getPrimaryUrl().replace("serviceA", "localhost:" + serviceA.port())
                .replace("serviceB", "localhost:" + serviceB.port()));
        route.setSecondaryUrl(route.getSecondaryUrl().replace("serviceA", "localhost:" + serviceA.port())
                .replace("serviceB", "localhost:" + serviceB.port()));
    }
    liveMigrationRouteLocator.setRoutingProperties(routingProperties);
    liveMigrationRouteLocator.refresh();

    serviceA.stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/test-path/.*")).willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withStatus(200).withBody("serviceA:test-path")));
    serviceB.stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/test-path/.*")).willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withStatus(200).withBody("serviceB:test-path")));
}

@After
public void after() {
    LiveMigrationProperties routingProperties = liveMigrationRouteLocator.getRoutingProperties();
    for (LiveMigrationRoute route : routingProperties.getRoutes().values()) {
        route.setPrimaryUrl(route.getPrimaryUrl().replace("localhost:" + serviceA.port(), "serviceA")
                .replace("localhost:" + serviceB.port(), "serviceB"));
        route.setSecondaryUrl(route.getSecondaryUrl().replace("localhost:" + serviceA.port(), "serviceA")
                .replace("localhost:" + serviceB.port(), "serviceB"));
    }
    liveMigrationRouteLocator.setRoutingProperties(routingProperties);
    liveMigrationRouteLocator.refresh();
}
```

I have multiple tests classes extending a base class that has the above implementation. Each test class has the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiveMigrationProperties.class)
public class RoutingTests extends LiveMigrationWireMockTests {
```

When running the tests I have debug logging around the refresh that occurs to see the issue. The log is at http://pastebin.com/preMTZ22. If you look for "Refreshing routes [#]" where # is the instance of the RouteLocator that is being used. The first test passes fine and you can see that it is using instance #0. Then the next test class runs and the ApplicationContext is refreshed so a new instance is created. You can see the "Refreshing routes [1]" along with "Get matching route [1]: ..." for each route that is looked up from the SimpleHostRoutingFilter.

Now the problem shows up when the next test class runs. The ApplicationContext refreshes again so the "Refreshing routes [2]" show up. When the SimpleHostRoutingFilter calls the RouteLocator you can see the log for "Getting matching route [1]: ...". This should be "Getting matching route [2]: ...". Due to this the SimpleHostRoutingFilter fails as it is trying to call http://serviceA instead of the dynamic port for the WireMock.

I have tried to recreate this in a simple test but I can't seem to reproduce it. The simple test does show the multiple instances being created but when it comes to doing the test only instance #0 is the one interacted with. http://pastebin.com/9jiCRmRE

https://github.com/ShawnTuatara/stack-overflow-spring-boot-test-zuul-autowired-instance

Comment: At the SpringOne Platform I had a chance to talk to Phil Webb. His temporary solution was to add @DirtiesContext to the test so that it rebuilt the ApplicationContext for each test. This resolved the issue. He also stated to open an issue with Zuul around this so I have done that:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1236